# Reinstate a deleted slide in Powerpoint's Notes Page view

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I received a Powerpoint presentation where someone deleted the slide in the Notes Page view.

[image]

After trying this myself, doing so is deceptively simple. Open View > Notes Page, then select the slide and hit the Del key. Funny enough, if we go back to the normal view, the slide is still there.

It seems the slide image in the Notes Page view is a special kind of Powerpoint shape, but I couldn't find any way to reinstate a deleted one. Does anybody know how to reinstate it?

I'm using Powerpoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some VBA will do it:

```
Sub ApplyMasterToNotes()

' Modified version of code originally posted to
' msnews.microsoft.com public newsgroups by
' David Foster in May of 1999

    Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    Dim oSl As Slide

    ' 700 is the control ID for Layout
    Set ctl = CommandBars.FindControl(Id:=700)
    ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNotesPage

    If (ctl Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "command not available"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

        ' go to the current slide
        ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (oSl.SlideIndex)
        DoEvents

        ' Bring up the dialog
        ctl.Execute
        DoEvents

        ' send it the needed keystrokes
        SendKeys "%r{enter}"
        DoEvents

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I'm surprised there is no manual way to do that on a specific slide.

Comment: Same here, but as far as I know, this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Manage Versions

There might be an old version you can recover.